# Is there a way to get Gmail labels in Thunderbid with POP so that to get only message from a label and delete them from the server?

Tags: gmail, imap, pop3, label

I have this Thunderbird client installed and this Gmail account.

I've tested some ways to download only emails from a specific label to my e-mail client and delete them from the server and I've seen that:

- in IMAP I can set to download only message from a specific label (or folder as named in Thunderbird)
- if I wish to delete e-mail from server but keep it on my local storage I have to use POP

So what I wish to do is:

1. I have some tags such as Work, Travel, Business
2. I want to download on my computer only emails from the tag Work and delete them from the server (or to set server so that when I delete an email from server it remains in my e-mail client)

More specific, I need POP3 with labels or even more specific I wish to have mails from the tag Work to be stored in my e-mail client and that from the other tags stored on the server (in my Gmail account).

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it with POP3: all your labels are local and doesn't correlate to server-side data in mailbox